# how to provide validation on to create SharePoint Date and time Column?

Tags: development, custom-list, column, calculated-column, validation

I want to create a SharePoint Date and time Column, so that the user is only allowed only to select a date 20 days ahead of today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test:

I created a Date and Time column named “Date”, and set column validation: [Date]>=TODAY()-20.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Calculated Column like this.  You'll notice I've referenced the default [Modified] date field, you can substitute this for an alternative date field.  Using the [Created] date field might work better for you or else make a new date field.

Back to my example - the only trouble is if someone changes the item the [Modified] date will change and the calculated column will also recalculate!

If you could give more detail in your question, then I'd see whether this would work for you or not.

[image]